# what is a type in C++?

Tags: c++, types

What all constructs(class,struct,union) classify as types in C++? Can anyone explain the rationale behind calling and qualifying certain C++ constructs as a 'type'.

Comment: The rationale is simple: because nobody could think up a better word to describe what you get from creating a class or struct.

Comment: @Jerry: that rationale is wrong. SLaks has the correct answer.

Comment: @Ken: Not really. First of all, use of the word "type" in describing programming languages predates C++ (and even C) by quite a while, so applying it when C++ came along was quite natural -- but only much later was the term formally defined. Second, quite a bit of what SLaks says is basically wrong wrt C++. Just for example, in C++ type means more about what operations are allowed than about what values are allowed. Different types can (and often do) support the same values but different sets of operations.

Comment: Just to give a couple of concrete examples, a `vector<long>` and `vector<string>` have completely different allowable values, but still have common operations. In the other direction, `vector<int>` and `valarray<int>` have basically the same allowable values, but different operations. Despite allowing the same values, `vector` and `valarray` are clearly different types. Despite allowing different values, `vector<string> and `vector<int>` are at least more closely related types if not necessarily identical. Despite formal definitions, "type" is mostly used because nobody has a better word.

Comment: @Jerry: you're splitting hairs. For someone who wants to understand why these are "types", SLaks wrote very simple and correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable contains a value.
A type is a specification of the value.  (eg, number, text, date, person, truck)

All variables must have a type, because they must hold strictly defined values.

Types can be built-in primitives (such as `int`), custom types (such as enums and classes), or some other things.

Answer (score 6):

> $3.9/1 - "There are two kinds of
>   types: fundamental types and compound
>   types. Types describe objects (1.8),
>   references (8.3.2), or functions
>   (8.3.5). ]"

Fundamental types are char, int, bool and so on.

Compound types are arrays, enums, classes, references, unions etc

Answer (score 3):

Other answers address the kinds of types C++ makes available, so I'll address the motivation part. Note that C++ didn't invent the notion of a *data type*. Quoting from the Wikipedia entry on [Type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system).

> a type system may be defined as "a
>   tractable syntactic framework for
>   classifying phrases according to the
>   kinds of values they compute"

Another interesting definition from the [Data Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) page:

> a data type (or datatype) is a
>   classification identifying one of
>   various types of data, such as
>   floating-point, integer, or Boolean,
>   stating the possible values for that
>   type, the operations that can be done
>   on that type, and the way the values
>   of that type are stored

Note that this last one is very close to what C++ means by "type". Perhaps obvious for the built-in (fundamental) types like `bool`:

- possible values are `true` and `false`
- operations - per definition of arithmetic operators that can accept `bool` as argument
- the way it's stored - actually not mandated by the C++ standard, but one can guess that on some systems a type requiring only a single bit can be stored efficiently (although I think most C++ systems don't do this optimization).

For more complex, user created, types, the situation is more difficult. Consider `enum` types: you know exactly the range of values a variable of an `enum` type can get. What about `struct` and `class`? There, also, your type declaration tells the compiler what possible values the `struct` can have, what operations you can do on it (operator overloading and functions accepting objects of this type), and it will even infer how to store it.

Re range of values, although huge, remember it's finite. Even a struct with N 32-bit integers has a finite range of possible values, which is `2^(32N)`.

Comment: Thanks that addresses the second part of my Q(For me, the first part is nicely addressed by Slaks answer).Unfortunate that I can't mark 2 answers. But thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1):

Cite from the book ["Bjarne Stroustrup - Programming Principles and Practice Using C++"](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), page 77, chapter 3.8:

> - A **type** defines a set of possible values and a set of operations (for an object).
> - An **object** is some memory that holds a value of a given type.
> - A **value** is a set of bits in memory interpreted according to a type.
> - A **variable** is a named object.
> - A **declaration** is a statement that gives a name to an object.
> - A **definition** is a declaration that sets aside memory for an object.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a matter of semantics to me...A type refers to something with a construct that can be used to describe it in a away that conforms to traditional Object Oriented concepts(properties and methods).  Anything that isn't called a type is probably created with a less robust construct.